# Why does this "re.findall" function, which uses a back reference, not work?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

```
re.findall(r"(i).*\1", "i am says i am")
```

The only thing that's returned is one "i".
I've searched for hours w/o finding a solution to this problem.

UPDATE: I was hoping to return "i am says i".

Comment: What are you hoping will happen? The only _captured_ group is `(i)`.

Comment: Use `re.finditer`, you may access the whole match values easily. Something like `print([x.group(0) for x in re.finditer(pattern, txt)])`

Comment: 'EVz0EZCvFFczBvWZxYwdE0bkgyge10fjxXwDwV0XTbAbBvbDvUUXafyx0xfxh3jeUYFAByB0UYyTdwbccUjecvzg0i12AFdwTVaZbBccDxZTvFAyy1320d1iwWTd0WBDXTXbxxzT0WWgdbjayacyddhibaaYWdUFyFTyxwYzyvxdeivyxv232dgawhE0ExTdWYbxwFzEbwb12hdcevgvBVWwbv0BwTWzzXUXyETDWB21wxadvyieijab03AcFTvUVxVyFwc0AFXdcwXTAhyvjaijjh2vZ0ZDvEazWbdTEdFVZef22kefgycgvdxfeB0BCUCCdYyzTzxBh1he20efcx2'

What I'm trying to do is capture the stings above where it begins w/a capital letter and ends w/the same capital letter. See example data above.

Comment: @CharlesSaag: Then you can use `print re.search(r'([A-Z]).*\1', str).group(0)` (see my answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way `findall` works, it will print capturing groups if they are present.

You can use `re.search`:

```
>>> print re.search(r'(i).*\1', "i am says i am").group(0)
i am says i
```

Or use additional grouping in `findall` as this:

```
>>> print re.findall(r'((i).*\2)', "i am says i am")[0][0]
i am says i
```

Answer (score 1):

When using parenthesis `(...)` in a `regex`, only things inside them are captured, so in your case, only `"i"s` are found.